# Uncaught ReferenceError: soapReq is not defined

Tags: javascript, undefined

Why is i soapReq 'undefined'?

```
var soapReq = GetFacilitiesSoapReq(sessionId);
console.log(soapReq)


function GetFacilitiesSoapReq(sessionId) {
    AbstractSoapReq.call(this); // invoke the super constructor
    this.getAjaxRequest = function() {
        var ajaxRequest = new GetFacilitiesAjaxReq();
        return ajaxRequest
    }
    this.getSOAPHead = function(sessionId) {
        return getSOAPHeadId(sessionId);
    }
    this.getSOAPBody = function() {
        return getSOAPBody("getFacilitiesForUser");
    } 
}
SignInSoapReq.prototype = Object.create(AbstractSoapReq.prototype);
```

I want to pass soapReq to a function as a parameter

Comment: I'n guessing it's undefined because you're trying to return from an ajax call, which is asynchronous ?

Comment: How about `new GetFacilitiesSoapReq(sessionId);`? Otherwise, you are clearly not returning anything from `GetFacilitiesSoapReq`, so it's no wonder `soapReq` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question with when I am logging it, so should not be undefined there should it?

Answer (score 0):

`soapReq` is undefined because the function `GetFacilitiesSoapReq` does not return anything.